# How to check for collisions with SFML (While using a Base class Entity)

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

```cpp
class Entity
{
private:
    //Functions
    void initiVariables();


protected:
    //Variables
    float velocity;
    sf::Sprite  sprite;
    sf::Texture* texture;

    MovementComponent* movementComponent;
    AnimationComponent* animationComponent;
    HitboxComponent* hitboxComponent;

    //Component Functions
    void setTexture(sf::Texture& texture);
    void **strong text**MovementComponent(float maxVelocity, float acceleration, float deacceleration);
    void AnimationComponent(sf::Sprite& sprite, sf::Texture& texture);
    void HitboxComponent(sf::Sprite& sprite, sf::Color wireColor, float wireThickness);

public:
    //Constructor & Deconstructor
    Entity();
    virtual~Entity();

    //Accessor
    const sf::FloatRect& getGlobalBounds() const; 

//when I check for Collsion sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersect(sprite.getGlobalBounds()) 
//it remains true for the entire time what am doing wrong?

    //Funtions
    void setPosition(const float x, const float y);
    virtual void move(const float x, const float y, const float& dt);
    virtual void update(const float& dt);
    virtual void render(sf::RenderTarget* target);
};
```

Comment: you're checking a collision against itself, of course it's always true

Comment: So how would I check for collisions between entities for instance player class, zombie class ect.....When they all share from the entity class?   I have already tried to use a getter function SF::FloatRect but the application keeps crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple inheritance from the `Entity` class. I don't know why your program crashes when returning `sf::FloatRect` objects. This should also be the correct solution to this problem.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Entity : public sf::RectangleShape { 
public:
    bool isColliding(Entity const& other) {
        return this->getGlobalBounds().intersects(other.getGlobalBounds());
    }
};

class Player : public Entity {};
class Zombie : public Entity {};

int main() {
    Player player;
    player.setPosition({ 200, 200 });
    player.setSize({ 100, 100 });

    Zombie enemy;
    enemy.setPosition({ 151, 151 });
    enemy.setSize({ 50, 50 });

    std::cout << player.isColliding(enemy);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much....I really need to start reading the debugger I believe the reason why it was causing my application to crash is that I'm using a new instance of the class and when I was calling for its global bounds it wasn't created yet so basically it was undefined.... Well I think that was the problem...Im still new  to c++ (Programming in general) so I might not be using the correct terminology